# Provide an interface to edit only one field of a content type?

Tags: nodes, entities, 6

I am trying to create a 'start a bounty' system, just the same as on this site using userpoints. There should be a link 'Start a bounty' which allows the question creator to start a bounty using his points. I am using userpoints for this purpose and I created a field where the user can select the number of points he would liek to give out for a correct answer. But this can only be done on node creation or while editing the entire node. The question is - how to be able to select the number of points only after clicking on 'start a bounty' without the need of editing all the remaining fields. So ideally there should be a popup with dropdown field that edits only this particular field. I guess one approach is to create a node edit form with this field only (is this possible at all?) and put it in the ajax popup... Any ideas / advice?

Answer (score 4):

There is a new module by Earl Miles, the creator of Views, that does this in Drupal 7 called the [Field API Pane Editor](http://drupal.org/project/fape).  Unfortunately, because this is a new solution for D7 and Earl Miles tends not to reinvent the wheel, I don't think there is any existing module that you can download for this use case in D6.

Comment: thanks. Do you think it is possible to do this in a different way? like printing a form with that field only?

Comment: I found this one - http://drupal.org/project/popups_subedit...maybe worth trying.

Comment: You could certainly try that.  It has very few installs though and never got a stable release; also, no work has been done on it in three years, so just set your expectations accordingly.  As for another way to do this, I personally don't know; hopefully someone else can chime in with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for exactly that feature, luckily I'm on 7 ;-)

Otherwise I would probably have used a hook_form_alter to hide the other fields on the edit form when you want to add the bounty. For example when you edit the form with /node/123/edit/bounty then hide other form field.

**Update:**

Checkout [jeditable](http://drupal.org/project/jeditable), [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) and this [blog](http://pixeljets.com/blog/improving-user-experience-using-dialogs-profile-edit-modal-forms)